# Using @Transactional with JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, jooq

I'm trying out JOOQ and the first thing I set my mind to is run a transactional unit test that will roll back automatically. I don't seem to get it to work and I'm not sure where to go from here. The logs shows that a transaction was started and rolled back. But the changes still get committed to the database.

**What can I do to make transactions in Spring work with JOOQ properly?**

```
2013-11-04 23:41:14,353 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Creating new transaction with name [insertPersons]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2013-11-04 23:41:14,369 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Acquired Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost/jooq-learn, UserName=jooq@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] for JDBC transaction
2013-11-04 23:41:14,376 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost/jooq-learn, UserName=jooq@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] to manual commit
2013-11-04 23:41:14,507 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Initiating transaction rollback
2013-11-04 23:41:14,508 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost/jooq-learn, UserName=jooq@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver]
2013-11-04 23:41:14,509 [main] DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager: Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost/jooq-learn, UserName=jooq@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] after transaction
2013-11-04 23:41:14,509 [main] DEBUG DataSourceUtils: Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

My test looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(TestConstants.contextConfigFile)
public class JooqTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JooqTest.class);

    private PersonService personService;


    @Inject
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }


    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void insertPersons() {
        PersonRecord john = new PersonRecord();
        john.setName("John");
        john.setAge(45);
        personService.save(john);
    }
}
```

I took the Spring context configuration from the JOOQ website:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      init-method="createDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jooq-learn"/>
    <property name="username" value="jooq"/>
    <property name="password" value="*****"/>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="config"/>
</bean>


<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5">
        <value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">MYSQL</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="6">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="7">
        <null/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you have MySQL properly setup with transactional tables? If they are MyISAM transactions aren't supported you need InnoDB type tables for that. Can you post your full testcase instead of only the method.

Comment: Yes it's indeed a MyISAM table. I will recreate the table and see what happens. I also updated the test to include the whole testcase.

Comment: Test is fine no further problems, just change the table type.

Comment: @M.Deinum I switched to InnoDB and now it works like expected. You saved my day :) Could you write an answer so I can properly reward you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL (older versions at least) by default uses [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) as the table type, this table type doesn't support transactions (see table 14.7 for support options). You need to switch to [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-introduction.html) tables, which does support transactions.

[image: MyISAM Storagte Engine Features]
Source: MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Links

- MyISAM [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)
- InnoDB [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-introduction.html)